# How to set a custom color in itext?

Tags: java, uitextfield, itext

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I'm generating a PDF document using iText in Java. I need to set the column headers of a table a different colour than the ones in the values columns. I have the color hexadecimal value from Photoshop. I'm using PdfPTable with chunks and paragraphs. how do I set them to a different colour, other than the ones predefined in the BaseColor enum?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DavidKroukamp thanks for the reply, I have come across this link. However the example is making use of the predefined colors in the BaseColor enum which is not what I am after...

Answer (score 21):

You'll need to take your 8-bit hexadecimal color value and convert it to 8-bit RGB values.

[How to convert hex to rgb using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129666/how-to-convert-hex-to-rgb)

Then you'll be able to create a new [BaseColor](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/BaseColor.html) with your RGB values.

```
cell.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(255, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Cell hcell = new Cell();   
Color color = WebColors.getRGBColor("red");
hcell.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Answer (score -5):

Take a look at this [site](http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/examples.html). Even though it says C# there are only Java codes. Let me know if you find it or not. I created an successful PDF system looking at those examples.