# How to code and decode RGB to Hex

Tags: java, hex, rgb, data-conversion

I am trying to make coder/decoder in Java so I could store RGB value in Hex format. I have coder like this:

```
System.out.println("#" + Integer.toHexString(label.getColor().getRed())
    + Integer.toHexString(label.getColor().getGreen())
    + Integer.toHexString(label.getColor().getBlue()));
```

and decoder like this:

```
System.out.println(decodeColor("#"
    + Integer.toHexString(label.getColor().getRed())
    + Integer.toHexString(label.getColor().getGreen())
    + Integer.toHexString(label.getColor().getBlue())));
```

Implementation of `decodeColor()` function is:

```
private RGB decodeColor(String attribute) {
    Integer intval = Integer.decode(attribute);
    int i = intval.intValue();
    return new RGB((i >> 16) & 0xFF, (i >> 8) & 0xFF, i & 0xFF);
}
```

When I run test program, I get this output:

- initial values are new RGB(15, 255, 45)

> <\label ... color="#fff2d">...</label>
>
> RGB {15, 255, 45}

- initial values are RGB(15, 0, 45)

> <\label ... color="#f02d">...</label>
>
> RGB {0, 240, 45}

So, in some cases it returns correct result, but in other its totally messed up. Why is that?

Comment: [This](https://www.google.co.in/?q=java+rgb+to+hex) might help.  Also refer to related questions on the right.

Comment: These two discussions could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607858/how-to-convert-a-rgb-color-value-to-an-hexadecimal-value-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129666/how-to-convert-hex-to-rgb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because #rrggbb always requires 2 hex digits per color component.

```
String s = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue());

Color c = Color.decode(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer intval = Integer.decode(attribute);
```

Here, the string `attribute` starts with a `#`, but it should start with `0x`.

```
private RGB decodeColor(String attribute) {
    String hexValue = attribute.replace("#", "0x");

    int i = Integer.decode(hexValue).intValue();
    return new RGB((i >> 16) & 0xFF, (i >> 8) & 0xFF, i & 0xFF);
}
```