# Swing setBackground Non-Color Class Values

Tags: java, swing, colors, awt, rgb

I am trying to color some areas of my swing UI, but feel limited by the use of the

```
.setBackground(Color.//color here
```

Is there any way I can use the hex values of more specific and unique colors (there isn't even a brown) in this? whenever I try I am shown an error.

Comment: You can use RGBA values to create your own colors and/or take a look at [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129666/how-to-convert-hex-to-rgb) examples of converting hex to RGB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
new Color(int r, int g, int b)
```

for RGB

```
new Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)
```

for ARGB (a=alpha transparence)

Comment: How could I implement that with a setup like this, for which I get an error stating that Color is undefined for int,int,int:                                         buton1.setBackground(Color(175, 178, 35));

Comment: button1.setBackground(new Color(175, 178, 35));

Comment: Ah forgive me my one lost word, and thank you, thank you very much!