# java : convert Hex color #RRGGBB to rgb r g b?

Tags: java, colors

my hex color string : `#ffffff`

i want simple way to convert string `#rrggbb` to `int r;` `int g;` `int b;`

```
int color = (int)Long.parseLong(myHexColor, 16);
int r = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = (color >> 0) & 0xFF;
```

this method is true?

thanks.

**Edit:______________________________**

```
String colorStr = "#ffffff";
int  r=  Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 1, 3 ), 16 );
int  g=  Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 3, 5 ), 16 );
int  b=  Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 5, 7 ), 16 );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert hex to rgb using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129666/how-to-convert-hex-to-rgb-using-java)

Comment: @Ormoz i want Separately int r / int g / int b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
    int  r=  Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 1, 3 ), 16 );
    int  g=  Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 3, 5 ), 16 );
    int  b=  Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 5, 7 ), 16 );
```