# How can I convert String to Int? will this value hex or dex?

Tags: string, int

in java i have

```
color_value="FFAAFF";
```

I have tried:

```
int color = Integer.parseInt(color_value);`
```

How can I convert it to int(hex) to add to `im_view.setBackgroundColor(int color);`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the language this is in (Java?). Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Your question is no about convert from String to Int, it's about converting from HEX, to another pattern like RGB, etc, in what pattern do you need it, also what prog. lang are u working on?

Answer (score 0):

As we have to guess the lang you're using, i'll assume it's java, what you actually need is to convert from HEX to RGB, if you are comfortable with AWT then you could use a built in func:

```
String color_value = "FFAAFF";
im_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.decode(color_value));
```

If don't want to use AWT, then you could do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4129692/3809894):

```
/**
 * 
 * @param colorStr e.g. "#FFFFFF"
 * @return 
 */
public static Color hex2Rgb(String colorStr) {
    return new Color(
            Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 1, 3 ), 16 ),
            Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 3, 5 ), 16 ),
            Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 5, 7 ), 16 ) );
}



im_view.setBackgroundColor(hex2Rgb(color_value));
```