# How to set a JColorChooser's Color with a String?

Tags: java, colors, hex, jcolorchooser

I'm making a program that reads a HEX code from a String. Then, it displays the color that it finds with the HEX code using a JColorChooser, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. How would I go about doing this? If I can't, then what is the second best solution?

PS: If this helps, here is some of the code:

```
    JColorChooser colorChooser = new JColorChooser();
    textField = new JTextField();

    JButton btnOk = new JButton("OK");
    btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String str = textField.getText();
            colorChooser.setColor(str);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129666/how-to-convert-hex-to-rgb-using-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string to int using (for example):

```
int color = Integer.parseInt(testField.getText(),16); //decode hex string
```