# How to convert a hex colour value stored as a String into an actual hex value in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

In short: how to get, for example... `#C990C0` from String data, as opposed to `"#C990C0"`?

I am prototyping something in Processing so ideally looking for a solution with no additional Java libraries.

In my data (json) hex colour values are stored as Strings.

There is an `unhex()` function in Processing that converts the String to an int, but this int is not meaningful as a representation of colour in Processing... and the `hex()` function converts to a String, not a hex type.

You can hardcode, say `fill(color(#C990C0))`, but you can't cast the String `"#C990C0"` to `#C990C0` to do this programmatically because there isn't a Hex primitive type.

Maybe the answer is to do something weird with the `byte` primitive type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert hex to rgb using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129666/how-to-convert-hex-to-rgb-using-java)

Comment: "but this int is not meaningful as a representation of colour in Processing" What does it convert it to, and what are you expecting instead? Is it because you need to convert `FFC990C0` instead of `#C990C0`?

Comment: Ok, thanks @xerx593. This is not exactly the solution I was looking for but it works to ... `import java.awt.Color;` and then get the r g b ints using `Color col = Color.decode(hexStringColour);` ... `int r = col.getRed();` etc.

Comment: My favorite was the [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4129754/592355) ! ..with byte shifts! ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track using [`unhex()`](https://processing.org/reference/unhex_.html).

Processing tries to be too nice in this case and it ends up being confusing.
Within the Processing editor you can use `color(#C990C0)` (though this wouldn't work in other editors easily).

Similarly `color` type is an `int` behind the scenes.
(It stores the 4 bytes: alpha, red, breen, blue as a 32bit integer)

And there's yet another catch with `unhex()`: number formatting.
You can use digits from `0` to `9` and letters `A` to `F`, but not other prefixes (such as `#` or `0x` for example).
On top of that it expects colours in `ARGB` (**not** `RGBA`) and that means you do need to specify the alpha value (otherwise, if the first two hex digits(alpha channel) is missing `00` is implied so your colour will be invisible).

In your case, you'd format the colour as: `"FFC990C0"`

Here's a test sketch:

```
JSONObject myData = JSONObject.parse("{\"color\":\"FFC990C0\"}");

color myColor = unhex(myData.getString("color"));

fill(myColor);
rect(0, 0, 50, 100);

// notice the colour doesn't show because the FF alpha prefix is missing
fill(unhex("C990C0"));
rect(50, 0, 50, 100);
```

**Update** After a bit of digging around it was interesting to spot this:

```
println(JSONObject.parse("{\"color\":0xC990C0}").get("color") instanceof String);
```

It prints `true` when I was expecting `false` (expecting `Integer` instead). (it does work as expected for `0-9`, but not `A-F`).

Processing thinks `0xC990C0` is a `String` (notice it has no double quotes surrounding the value), probably due to [this](https://github.com/processing/processing4/blob/main/core/src/processing/data/JSONObject.java#L1556).
Also, [`unhex()`](https://github.com/processing/processing4/blob/main/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java#L9379) uses [`Long.parseLong()`](https://github.com/processing/processing4/blob/main/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java#L9379) which limits the usage of `0x`, `#` or similar prefixes.

You can use `Long.decode("#C990C0")` instead though (e.g. `color myColor = Long.parseLong(myData.getString("color")).intValue();`)
.